# Continuity of $e^x-1$ with $\epsilon-\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^- \to \mathbb{R} \quad x \mapsto e^x-1 ,\; \epsilon >0,\; x<0$.
Now, in order to prove continuity at $x_0=0$ having  $|x|<\delta$, we can follow:
$|f(x)-f(0)|= |e^x-1| \overset{|x|<1}{\leq} \frac{|x|}{1-|x|}\overset{\delta \neq 1}{<} \frac{\delta}{1-\delta} \overset{!}{=}\epsilon$. So in total we need $|x|<1, \delta \neq 1  \land \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$. As latter is $<1$ for $\delta= \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ we have shown continuity.
Problem: the master solution shows the following $\delta$, which I don't get:
$\delta= \begin{cases} \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} & \epsilon <1\\
\frac{1}{2} & \epsilon \geq 1\end{cases}$. I noticed that at $\epsilon=1$ the terms are equal, but why the restriction for big $\epsilon$ as the above term is anyway always smaller 1?

Comment: Your expression of $\;\delta\;$ is ok, it is not necessary to write that $\;\delta=\frac12\;$ for any $\;\varepsilon\geqslant1\;.$

Comment: ok thanks, i thought i may have missed a clue, but then it may be ok.